# Grails 3 call taglib from a service

Tags: grails, grails-services

I'm trying to use grails internal taglib from a service but I receive this error:

```
No signature of method: MyService.message() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[code:default.app.name]]
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
class MyService {

    def myMethod() {
        def appName = message(code: 'default.app.name')
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Grails 3**

The solution is to inject the `grailsApplication` object and use its context to get the [taglib bean](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3.1.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ApplicationTagLib.groovy):

```
class MyService {

    def grailsApplication

    def myMethod() {
        def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
        def appName = g.message(code: 'default.app.name')
    }

}
```

**Grails 2**

With older grails version the class package is [slightly different](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.5.x/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ApplicationTagLib.groovy):

```
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')
```

If you try to use this package with newer grails version (3+), you'll receive an error:

```
No bean named 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib' is defined.
```

**Custom taglib**

With any version, if you need to use your custom taglib from a service just use a code like this:

```
def c = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('my.pkg.HelpfulTagLib')
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a slightly different approach for the ApplicationTagLib, that relies on the imports you're using and so are less prone to error independently of the version of Grails: `ApplicationTagLib g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean( ApplicationTagLib.class.name ) as ApplicationTagLib` or without types if you prefer `def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean( ApplicationTagLib.class.name )`