# Grails 3.3.9 call taglib from a service

Tags: grails

I would like to call the Grails taglib to get validation message strings in my service to return as part of a JSON response. I have tried using:

`def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')`
`def appName = g.message(code: 'default.app.name')`

Or

`ApplicationTagLib g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean( ApplicationTagLib.class.name )`

I am getting a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib' available.  Has this been moved in Grails 3.3.9 and above and if so where?

My build.gradle has: apply plugin:org.grails.grails-web". Do I need to add another dependency?

I used the following as a guide but it doesn't seem to work this way anymore:
[Grails 3 call taglib from a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926186/grails-3-call-taglib-from-a-service)

Comment: If you're only reading messages, use the `messageSource` bean. See [Reading Messages in Grails Artifacts with MessageSource](https://docs.grails.org/3.3.9/guide/i18n.html#_reading_messages_in_grails_artifacts_with_messagesource)

Comment: That was what I wanted thanks.